# How could binlog of mysql and redo log of innodb stay consistent?

Tags: mysql

I am reading the internals of MySQL. And I have a question about the 2 logs of MySQL: redo log and binlog.

If one transaction commit triggers 2 kinds of logs, and one log is in MySQL level and the other is in the engine level, how could MySQL guarantee that 2 logs are consistent and logged together?

Comment: maybe better suited to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: sure, let me fix this.